# Multiple settings with Django and AppEngine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

On my current setup I have multiple settings files for local, staging and production environments. I just have different `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` value for each server.

But now I'm trying to move to AppEngine and I'd like to know how I could deploy to different AppEngine instances with different `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable values.

I know there's `env_variables` option on `app.yaml` but I didn't find any way I could override it in `appcfg.py` as I can do for `version` and `application` options.

Is there any way I can do what I need?

Comment: Are you hosting your environments on the same app engine project or multiple projects? You can use `appengine_config.py` along with setting `os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']` to handle it dynamically

Comment: I'm using separate projects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use something similar to this for our webapp2 project inside the `appengine_config.py` file in our application root. The idea is that we swap out config based on the app id of the project. I made up constants for the example but it should give you enough to get started.

```
import os
from google.appengine.api import app_identity

app_id = app_identity.get_application_id()

if os.environ.get('SERVER_SOFTWARE', 'dev').lower().startswith('dev'):
    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'local settings'
elif app_id == MY_DEV_ID:
    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'dev settings'
elif app_id == MY_STAGING_ID:
    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'staging settings'
elif app_id == MY_PROD_ID:
    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'prod settings'
else:
    raise ValueError("Unknown app id %" % app_id)
```

Comment: Do you have different app.yaml for each environment?

Comment: @filias I do not. I have a single `app.yaml` and deploy using the application id flag of `appcfg` or the `--project` flag of `gcloud` to specify which project to deploy to.